# Как бороться с этой бот атакой которая нагрузку создает?

Tags: php, wordpress

[image: Вот]

Получается атакует от wp-loing.php до картинок запросами дикими не могу понять либо это сам сервер делает что бы свои услуги продать мне либо что? как заблокировать такое ? по айпи делал но айпишники поменялись

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Что за файл wp-loing.php? Имеется в виду wp-login. php? Его нет в логе.

Comment: нет я  к примеру тот файл я скрыл и все равно запросы были уже на другие файлы хаотично

Comment: Что делает некий zz1.jpg в папке wp-content? Там не должно быть картинок. Почему 302? Что за правила у вас в .htaccess? Покажите его. Тут больше похоже на заражение, чем на бот-атаку.

Comment: Думаете заражение ? Дикая просто нагрузка на сервер zzz1.jpg это просто лого и тд а 302 потому что я отвязал домен пока что

Comment: У вас хостинг на ps.kz? Попросите их проверить сайт на вирусы и выслать вам список файлов для ознакомления. Чистите их, обновляйте плагины, проверьте список, там могут откровенно старые/дырявые плагины.

Comment: Поставьте плагин Wordfence и запустите сканирование

Comment: Да он показал 9000 тыс защитил и 3000 пропустил установи премиум

Comment: Ну, как я и предположил - у вас сайт тотально заражён. Сносите ядро, заливайте заново, переустановите все плагины и темы и надёжных источников

Comment: Спасибо буду делать сейчас

Comment: @ anuarthor Никакое это не заражение, просто пытаются админку найти. Зачем? Во первых возможно хотят определить CMS сайта, а во вторых цель может быть взлом сайта. Перетерпите если не пройдет, пишите хостеру.